# Adding spaces to duplicate elements in list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following list1:

```
['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom', 'Tom']
```

I would like to add a space to duplicate values in order to obtain the following ouput:

```
['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom ', 'Tom  ']
```

As Tom is repeated 2 times the 1st it has I space and the second 2 spaces at the end

I was thing in using a line of code like this

```
[ f'{x} ' for x in list1 if .... ]
```

But not really sure how could I apply it for my case

This is what I tried so far:

```
from collections import Counter
d =  Counter(list1) 
res = [k for k, v in d.items() if v > 1]
print([ f'{x} ' for x in res ])
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it including the addition of spaces?

Comment: What have you tried so far (whether it is simple loops or list comprehension)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you want to add spaces as the number of occurences until each element, you can use [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) method of lists. Then multiply this count with `" "`:

```py
l = ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom', 'Tom']

res = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    cnt = l[:i].count(l[i])
    res.append(l[i] + " "*cnt)
```

Or in one line:

```py
res = [l[i] + " " * l[:i].count(l[i]) for i in range(len(l))]
```

And both give as expected:

```py
['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom ', 'Tom  ']
```

---

Another different approach can be to use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and *"remember"* the counts in one go (`O(n)`), instead of counting for each element (`O(n^2)`):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

l = ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom', 'Tom']

res = []
d = defaultdict(int)
for x in l:
    cnt = d[x]
    res.append(x + " "*cnt)
    d[x] = cnt + 1
```

This way if an element is seen for the first time its count will be initiazized to `0`.

---

Or, lastly, without any imports. We can just use a regular dictionary and take advantage of the [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method:

```py
l = ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom', 'Tom']

res = []
d = {}
for x in l:
    res.append(x + " "*d.setdefault(x, 0))
    d[x] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives the output that you want:

```
x = ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom', 'Tom']
z=[]
for y in range(len(x)):
    z.append(x[y] + " "*x[:y].count(x[y]))
```

This yields a z of `['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom ', 'Tom  ']`

As a list comprehension, this looks like:

```
[x[y] + " "*x[:y].count(x[y]) for y in range(len(x))]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good opportunity to use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) collection, like this:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom', 'Tom']
nums = Counter()
ans = []

for name in lst:
    ans.append(name + ' ' * nums[name])
    nums[name] += 1
```

The trick is to keep track of the number of occurrences of the name using the `Counter`, and update it as we go. Notice that the `' ' * nums[name]` part simply says: "print this number of spaces". It works as expected:

```
ans
=> ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom ', 'Tom  ']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that avoids repeatedly using count on the original list.

We build the output list, keeping track with a `collections.Counter` of the previously encountered items:

```
from collections import Counter

data = ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom', 'Tom']

out = []
counts = Counter()
for item in data:
    out.append(item + ' '*counts[item])
    counts.update((item,))

print(out)
# ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Tom ', 'Tom  ']
```

Note the comma in `counts.update((item,))`: as update expects an iterable, we pass it a tuple containing just one element, our item. Passing directly the string would count the individual letters.